# Getting the text from a node using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="top">
    <p>Blah.</p>
    I want <em>this</em> text.
</div>
```

What is the XPath notation to extract the string "`I want <em>this</em> text.`"?
EDIT: I don't necessarily want a single XPath expression to extract the string. Selecting multiple nodes, and iterating over them to produce the sentence, would be great as well.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(myHtml);
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("??????");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to extract, nodes or a string?

If you want nodes, `"I want <em>this</em> text."` is an XML fragment consisting at the top level of *two text nodes and an `<em>` element*, which has a text node child. Since it has multiple nodes at the top level, you need to use `SelectNodes("xpath expression a la @Alejandro")` rather than `SelectSingleNode()` to extract them.

If you want a string, again you need to use SelectNodes(); and then iterate over the selected nodes and concatenate the outerHTML of each one. See [here](http://www.fairnet.com/post/2010/08/28/Html-screen-scraping-with-HtmlAgilityPack-Library.aspx) for a good example of something similar.

Also, it's a little unclear from your example what XPath expression would in general give you what you want. E.g. do you want everything after the initial `<p>...</p>` under `<div class="top">`? Or do you want all text under the `<div>` except *all* `<p>` elements? Or maybe something else? Of course if @Alejandro's XPath expressions work for you then it's already well-specified enough.

Comment: I want to extract the string "`I want <em>this</em> text.`"

Comment: Using SelectNodes() and iterating over each node, if I have to.

Comment: @grautur: ok... see the example I linked to in my latest edit. I'm having a hard time finding documentation for the HTML Agility Kit ... do you know where it is? I downloaded a chm help file but it doesn't work in Windows 7 apparently.

Comment: I got it now, thanks! I used Alejandro's expression. [I didn't realize I had to select multiple nodes, and didn't know that "OuterHtml" existed.] Your explanation was super helpful, though, so I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
/div[@class='top']/p[.='Blah.']/following-sibling::node()
```

or

```
/div[@class='top']/node()[not(self::p)]
```

Comment: @Alejandro, he's put the XPath inside SelectSingleNode(), but no single XPath expression will get him the result he wants.

Comment: @Alejandro: This gives me "I want ", but not the rest of the sentence. @LarsH: It doesn't have to be SelectSingleNode, I'm just looking for any way to get the whole sentence (with the html still intact).

Comment: Oh, I see now. It gives me the entire sentence if I use SelectNodes() [as per LarsH's suggestion].

Comment: @grautur: Yes, you have to use `SelectNodes()` (as @LarsH point out there is no web documentation aviable for Agility Pack).